# Error with GuzzleHttp trying to decode a JSON string into an array in a php 7 installation

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to convert a json string into an array with php.

My php version is 7.0

### I'm getting this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   GuzzleHttp\json_decode()

### Here's the code with the issue:

```
$adjunto1 = $value['archivo']; 
$adjunto2 = json_decode($adjunto1, TRUE); //this is teh line with the error
```

### $value['archivo'] comes from the database, and if I see inside I get:

```
string(155) "{"nombre":["ejemploxls"],"archivoContenido":["id.--ejemploxls--fecha-26-04-2020-10-08.xls"],"fecha":["26-04-2020-10-08"],"size":[5632],"extension":["xls"]}"
```

When I converted the array to a json string using json_encode(), the array looked like this:

```
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "ejemplo.xls"
    ["type"]=>
    string(24) "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/php7M0gVS"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(5632)
  }
```

What is this error? What is *GuzzleHttp*?

Comment: Seems that you have some kind of implicit import of GuzzleHttp. To solve that problem let's try to add a slash before function call: `$adjunto2 = \json_decode($adjunto1, TRUE);`.
If you want to obtain much more detailed answer, add a list of you php-imports (`use`), please.

Comment: Using \ got it sorted, thank you @MaksimIakunin! Please add it as an answer, so I can accept it. Why I did an implicit import of GuzzleHttp? I didn't even know about GuzzleHttp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you have some kind of implicit import from GuzzleHttp.

[Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) is an extensible PHP HTTP client.

[Here is](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/functions.php#L126) a wrapper for `json_decode` php-function from GuzzleHttp namespace, that may cause your problem.

As a quick soluiton just add a slash before function call:

```
$adjunto2 = \json_decode($adjunto1, TRUE);
```

If you want to obtain much more detailed answer from me, plese, add a list of you [use-statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) from beginning of your php-file. Also list of `includes` (if there is any) would be helpful. I need some more context to be more precise.